# XMLHttpRequest post request to Laravel5

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

```
    XMLHttpRequest.open("POST", +"/"+ UploadingURL+"/"+parametername+"/"+namesend);
```

I have the function above to upload a video file. How can i retrevie the data from a route in post route in laravel5.

How to build the route and the controller to upload files and save the name of file in database.

Comment: The code you've provided so far won't upload any kind of file (at least, not by itself). Assuming you do have working JS that uploads a file, you would retrieve it in your PHP the same way that you do any other file upload - there's nothing JavaScript specific about it.

Comment: Fixed it. For all post request we need a token in the form in laravel5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this.

The problem was with tokens.

Laravel requires tokens on post request so you have to put _token variable on data when you make a post request on Laravel.